# Initial Excel Workbook Path

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spread sheet which, after 30 seconds, saves itself as a new file on the desktop so the original file is not edited. I want the path of the original file, so i add -

```
"ActiveWorkbook.Path"
```

But, this doesnt work correctly now, as when the file is saved as a new name after 30 seconds, it takes the

```
"ActiveWorkbook.Path"
```

of the newley named file, which in this case is the desktop.

Is there anyway in getting the Path to the initial file, before it got saved ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to store it in a variable at the start of the code:

```
Dim originalPath As String
originalPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

Then, you can refer back to it as needed.

Comment: I already have it within a variable, but it looks at the **"Active"** workbook, which, when it saves becomes the active workbook